# command to find port used by IIS 6.0 website

Tags: windows, iis-6, port

Given the name of a website and an app pool in IIS 6.0, is there a command that can list the port number used by that website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs get W3SVC/1234/ServerBindings

where 1234 is the website Identifier number found in IIS Manager "Web Sites" list.

Comment: Can I get the website identifier number by a command as well?